# Phase noise improvement after gain compression

Tags: amplifier, cmos

The very curious question/observation is about the improvement in phase noise for input power levels greater than P1dB.

I am designing a cascode 3 stage distributed amplifier in 65nm CMOS technology. My input referred P1dB is -4.5 with -152dBc/Hz phase noise and I am getting -170dBc/Hz phase noise at P1dB=28. I am not sure what is going wrong at large power levels. After P1dB=28, the phase noise degrades again.

I think the phase noise should degrade as the amplifier becomes non-linear i.e. in my case P1dB is -4.5. So I expect degradation in noise beyond P1dB but it seems getting better.

I'm not able to find any particular reference for this case to understand the reason behind it.

Comment: So, this is really surprising, indeed: Compression is a non-linear amplifier behaviour, and hence leads to intermodulation, which hence *introduces* phase noise (phase noise being multiplicative and not additive in nature). Could you point us at a source for the claim that compression leads to *improved* phase noise?

Comment: I experienced this sought of behavior in my distributed amplifier design in CMOS technology. For power levels greater then Psat, my phase noise at 10KHz offset is getting better, say from -155 to -160dBc/Hz.

Comment: Would be wise to add that information to your question, and maybe quite a bit more information on your amplifier architecture. Also, describe your measurement in- and output.

Comment: I am designing a cascode 3 stage distributed amplifier in 65nm CMOS technology. My input referred P1dB is -4.5 with -152dBc/Hz phase noise and I am getting -170dBc/Hz phase noise at P1dB=28. I am not sure what is going wrong at large power levels. After P1dB=28, the phase noise degrades.

Comment: **Edit** your question to include that edit. Few readers will even read these comments!

Comment: What do you think is going wrong? What do you expect and how do your observations diverge from that expectation? I am also unclear whether you mean 28dB or "after 28dB" by large power levels.

Comment: I think the phase noise should degrade as the amplifier becomes non-linear i.e. in my case P1dB is -4.5. So I expect degradation in noise beyond P1dB but it seems getting better.

Comment: Again : add that to the question! I'll just note that clipping an analog signal to a clean supply will ultimately approximate a square wave whose noise content is that of the supply.

Comment: Sorry, could I please get some more explanation.